# How to keep git from tracking all files that end with a "~"?

Tags: git

I'm using Gedit, and each time I save a file, Gedit creates a copy of it, and the name of the copy always ends with a ~. The problem is, Git always tries to track these files, and I don't want that! Is there a way to still be able to use `git add .`, but add just those files that do not end with ~?

Comment: No, no Arthur Denting necessary.  As far as I know, it's valid to gitignore .gitignore; I usually do.

Comment: Re: Edit. It's not neccesarily a good idea to ignore .gitignore. I'm pretty sure these settings are of use anywhere you clone your repo. We put our ignores in version control and are very happy about it, because only one developer needs to set it up.

Comment: I also use gedit and it creates backup files. If you want make ged it not to do that - change settings of the program: edit > preferences> editor> uncheck flag "create backups copy".  After that - you will not see any ~ tilda files.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You want a [gitignore file](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).

If you want to nuke everything that ends with a tilde (which should be safe; I can't imagine a reasonable use-case where that's bad), make sure the following line is in your `.gitignore` file at the top of your repo's folder hierarchy:

```
*~
```

---

If you *also* want to get rid of those tilde files laying around in your local file system, you can. It'd be best to make Gedit put its backup files somewhere else. JEdit and VIm, the two editors I use most, [have such settings](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory), and it's lots cleaner to keep those somewhere else than loading up gitignore.

Unfortunately, Gedit doesn't have that option. The best it can do is to turn off the `~` backups. **Before you get worried, the worst case is that you lose what was in the file [immediately before you saved](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit).** That's not a worst-case -- that's why you've got this in a git repo, right?

<sup>NOTE: If you want to keep the `~` suffixed files locally, do. The .gitignore you set up, above, will keep you from accidentally sharing them.</sup>

[You can turn off `~` suffixed backups like this](http://chrisjean.com/2009/02/09/getting-rid-of-tilde-files-in-ubuntu/)

> To prevent Gedit from creating these backups in the future, open up Gedit, open up the Preferences dialog (Edit > Preferences), select the Editor tab, remove the check in the “Create a backup copy of files before saving” option, and click Close. After doing this, Gedit will no longer make the backups with tildes all over the place.

Comment: Why would you want to turn off the backups? They have saved me countless times in the past.

Comment: Well, obviously to remove the tildes, but I agree with you (see above).  I wanted to find a way to move all backup files to a specific dir, like in VIm (I use a line `set backupdir=C:\\vimBackups` in my vimrc on Windows, eg), but that doesn't seem to exist for Gedit.  But see above.  *Fixed*.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter -- care to explain?  Is there now a better way to have Gedit save backup files that doesn't leave artifacts on your file system?

Comment: If backups have saved you many times, don't exclude them. Our database is so big that magento cannot handle the backup. We use mysqldump to do this. In that case you can exclude it.

Comment: this useful answer tells you how to turn the back up feature on gedit off: http://askubuntu.com/a/90520/453324

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Looks like exactly the same stuff from the [Tilde be gone](http://chrisjean.com/2009/02/09/getting-rid-of-tilde-files-in-ubuntu/) link in the answer... but it does have a picture! Thanks. ;^)

Comment: @ruffin you are absolutely right! I completely missed the link the first time i perused your answer but when i clicked on it i saw that it simply duplicated what you had already said!

Answer (score 105):

[gitignore](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) is the way to go. Just add `*~` to `.gitignore` at the root of you repo.

Comment: This is a better solution because its a pain to configure each every program to not create `~` files (e.g. emacs).

Comment: @TahirHassan But better solution... than what? The first thing I suggested was to create a .gitignore file. If you *also* want to clean up your local repo so it doesn't have `~` files everywhere, I *also* explain how to do that. ;^) You really aren't playing without a net by doing it. You only save yourself one edit back with the tilde files, and that's not a lot of practical help when you're already using git. That said, @filmor did beat me to saying OP should use .gitignore by a few seconds...

Answer (score 8):

To add on to what @filmor said, you can create a global gitignore file so that all repositories will ignore the backup files:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

This will tell git to look in your $HOME path for a `.gitignore_global` file, which is where you can place the `*~` rule.

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing the answers:
If you have tilde files with extension, like Sketchup, which creates backup files ending with "~.skp", then you need to add `*~.skp` in your .gitignore file. **Or** change `skp` for the extension of the software you are using. **Or** use `*~.*` if you are sure that all files ending with tilde with all extensions are safely to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother adding a `.gitignore` file when you can edit the plaintext file `.git/info/exclude`. "When deciding whether to ignore a path, git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources" https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html

If you add `*~` to a line in the `.git/info/exclude` file in your git repository. Git will ignore that pattern and all of the files ending in tildes.

Comment: I'm not the one to down vote, but its a bad answer, the ".git" folder is not shared with all of the repository users, the .gitignore file does (by default, it might be changed in specific project..). 
usually *~ files are temp backup files and you don't want anyone to add them by mistake so it should be set for all of the repository users.