# ~ appended to a collection of file names in git repository?

Tags: git

I have a fairly small git repository of under 1,000 files. Ever since a merge was performed I had a bunch of .orig files generated, which I read is just the diff tool providing a backup (the merge seemed to be successful). However there are other files with `~` added right to the end of the file. Why might these have appeared, ie are they safe to delete?

Comment: Those may be editor temporary files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829708/how-to-keep-git-from-tracking-all-files-that-end-with-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're probably safe to delete - they're most likely backup files created by your text editor. However, why don't you just add it to your `.gitignore`? You can use `*~`.

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to recursively delete them?

Comment: try deed02392's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to remove all the files after it was advised they were probably temporary copies created by my editor.

```
git status -su | grep -e"~$" | cut -f2 -d" " | xargs rm
```