# Cannot remove ~ from git

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Here is a screenshot of my directory.

[image]

When I push it to GitHub, it looks like this:

[image]

I have googled and tried to remove the ~/.vscode-root in my git, and added it to .gitignore but it didn't work. Please give me a solution. Thanks

Comment: Try `rm -r ./~` so the tilde doesn't expand to `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, try to unstage the folder or file you want to ignore with this command. Flag -r is needed if it's a folder to do it recursively.

```
git rm --cached '~' -r
```

USE SINGLE QUOTES AROUND ~ so that terminal understands and doesn't give file paths error. This will unstage whole ~ folder contents. If you need specific file inside ~ folder, use like this:

```
git rm --cached '~/.vscode-root'
```

Then, add or edit the .gitignore file with the name of folder or file at every newline like this

> *~

This will ignore everything inside tilde folder. If you only want to ignore specific file

> ~/.vscode-root

After that, git add commit and push as usual. Plus it's better to change the dir name of tilde to something else because linux terminals(if you are using linux env) may throw you errors.

Comment: I got an error when I was trying to use your command: fatal: pathspec '.vscode-root' did not match any files

Answer (score 1):

Another way to avoid ~ expansion to HOME would be to escape it:

```
git rm \~
git add .
git commit -m "remove ~ folder"
git push
```

Also, [consider adding  `*~` to your `.gitignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11829746/6309).

Answer (score 1):

```
git rm --cached '~/.vscode-root'
```

Answer (score 0):

Github tracks a file if it was already being tracked even if it is `.gitignore`. To make git completely forget about it and stop tracking it, you need it to be removed from the the index.

To remove a file from being tracked by git.

1. Add the `<file name>` in `.gitignore`.

   Example: Add `~/.vscode-root` in gitignore.
2. Now you need to remove the file from git tracking. To do this:

   ```
   git rm --cached ~/.vscode-root
   # the above line deletes the file from staging area without deleting the file locally 

   # or use the below line to actually remove the folder.
   rm -rf ~/.vscode-root

   # commit this change(choosing one of above two options) to remove git tracking of folder
   git add  ~/.vscode-root
   git commit -m "removing files to untrack them"
   ```